# Best way to pull database entries from textfield input

Tags: java, android

I am looking to create an app in the Java language for Android devices.

I am looking to create an application where the user can type an observation in a textfield. There would then be a database with entries that the observation can link to (Age categories, creative, physical etc.)

How will I be able to filter database entries through a textfield entry?

Links with articles explain how or a direct answer is fine.

Comment: For example a user may enter:
- Person added 1 and 1 together using the correct method

A database entry would have:
Can add basic sums together 

The app would then present that database entry as a potential match to entered text.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `SQLite` as a backend for your database, because it is built into the Android system and therefore available to all apps. [Here](http://icyarena.com/view/android-sqlite-database-tutorial-(create,-insert,-update,-delete,-filter)) is  a complete tutorial for creating an app with a filter-`EditText`. There is a "download source code"-button at the very end of the article if you want to see a sample app.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking to have a large text area and to hide the database entries though sql lite seems a good start